# How to add a local version of code to localhost GoCD pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, go-cd

I have created a local GoCD server and agent so that I can test my modification of code before committing and getting deployed. This is specially used for Automation purpose. I can only see few options

1. Git
2. Subversion
3. Mercurial
4. Perforce
5. Team Foundation Server
6. Pipeline
7. Package

[image]

What is the best way to select local directory to run my script on my local GoCD server?

If this post does belong here please let me know I will remove instead of degrading my post.

Answer (score 0):

Local builds using GoCD can be achieved at least with Git when the project folder contains a Git repository. Assuming that `projectx`, the next steps will show how an automated local build using GoCD and Git can be set up.

First a GIT repository with a master brach has to be created. The master branch becomes visible after performing the first commit operation.
My assumption here is, that `projectx` is located in `file:///Users/jdoe/`.

```sh
$ cd projectx
$ git init --bare
$ git add <your sources and build files here>
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
```

During pipeline or material creation , the selected *Git* has to be selected as *Material Type*. The selected branch will be `master` by default.

Now, the URL can be added, pointing to the local Git repository.
For this example it would be: `file:///Users/jdoe/projectx/`.

[image: adding a local Git repository as material]

If the repository is reachable and the `master` branch exists can be verified by clicking on *CHECK CONNECTION*.

[image: check connection to local Git]

This works with GoCD 19.1.0 on OSX. Of course, the path name must be adusted depending on the system used (for Windows there must be a drive letter). But generally, GoCD accepts an URL with file-protocol for Git materials.

On each new commit, the GoCD agent will clone the repository and attempt a build.

**An alternate repository setup**

Depending on the size of the project and the workflow, it is possibly not ideal to run a build on every commit. Therefore it can be of advantage, to create a bare repository (git init --bare) at a different location and configure the GoCD pipeline to use the bare repository. The working repository the could be connected using `git remote add` to the bare repository.
Then, each `git push` to the remote would trigger a GoCD build. A single push then could contain multiple commits or a single commit.